# How to export database schema in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am having a hard time figuring out how to export a database creation script in VS 2012. Is this possible?

Comment: is it possible generate script form all sql serer object like SMO via Server Explorer Or sql server object window in vs? but how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what exactly you mean by your question. If you simply want to generate a create database / tables / views / and optionally include data, then you could use sql management studio (express, if need be) to generate scripts (via SMO) and then simply execute your script at runtime, alternatively i think you can generate scripts from the 'server explorer' tool window if you have a registered SQL server.

However, if you intend to version the database schema, and provide schema versioning/data versioning once a database is in place, they you'll want to look at SQL Server data tier applications, which is more of a toolset and libraries for database lifecycle management (buzzword overdrive enabled).

The tooling for VS data tier app projects is wrapped up in the [SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx), which basically adds a slimmed down version of SQL SMS object explorer to the project window when working with database projects, and adds some pretty awesome project configuration capabilities when compared to just executing a pre-generated SQL script at runtime.

Comment: is it possible generate script form all sql serer object like SMO via Server Explorer Or sql server object window in vs? but how?

Answer (score -1):

If it's not giving you the update or generate script button, go into schema change options, under the general tab, uncheck "Block on possible data loss". Be sure to compare after changing this option.

Answer (score -2):

Additionally, if you want to retrieve all comments from all tables in your database:

SELECT sys.Tables.Name,Value
FROM sys.Tables
INNER JOIN sys.extended_properties ON sys.extended_properties.major_id = sys.Tables.object_id